# Running all targets at once in a Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile as below

```
all:
    bison -d -v parser.y
    flex  -o parser.lex.c parser.lex
    gcc  -o cparser parser.lex.c parser.tab.c -lfl -lm 
clean:
    rm parser.tab.h parser.tab.c parser.output parser.lex.c
```

When i ran make in terminal  then it only runs target `all`.

I have tried by adding
 `.PHONY:all clean` and `.PHONY:clean` even though it only runs `all` .
What are the changes i should make in Makefile so that it runs all target ?

System Configurations:
Ubuntu 14.10
GNU Make 4.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to run `all` and `clean` when you just type `make`? That's usually not useful since that would clean up what you just built (though in your case I see that your `clean` target doesn't actually do that).

To do this you want something like.

```
all: cparser clean

cparser:
    bison -d -v parser.y
    flex  -o parser.lex.c parser.lex
    gcc  -o cparser parser.lex.c parser.tab.c -lfl -lm

clean:
    rm parser.tab.h parser.tab.c parser.output parser.lex.c
```

Though that is still a fairly poor makefile and doesn't take advantage of *any* of the benefits that `make` affords you (like intelligently rebuilding things only when their prerequisites change).

I would suggest you probably want something more like this.

```
.PHONY: all
all: cparser

parser.lex: parser.y
    bison -d -v parser.y

parser.lex.% parser.tab.%: parser.lex
    flex  -o parser.lex.c parser.lex

cparser: parser.lex.c parser.tab.c
    gcc  -o cparser parser.lex.c parser.tab.c -lfl -lm

.PHONY: clean    
clean:
    rm parser.tab.h parser.tab.c parser.output parser.lex.c cparser
```

Assuming I recall correctly that `flex` will generate both the `parser.lex.c` and `parser.tab.c` files at the same time.

Note also that the prerequisites are chained and that `clean` now cleans the binary as well. You don't need to run `make clean` to have things rebuild correctly this way.

Comment: Thanks . `parser.output  parser.tab.h  parser.tab.c` these files are generated by `flex -d -v parser.y `  and `flex parser.lex` generates `lex.yy.c` .

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to `make` all targets in the Makefile (you *really* don't want to, this is usually not how you use makefiles), you can add a target that has all the other targets of the Makefile as it's prerequisites:

```
.PHONY: all_targets
all_targets: all clean

.PHONY: all
all:
    # ... command script
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    # ... command script
```

In this particular example, making `all` followed by `clean` is complete nonsense, since `all` would build all files and `clean` would remove them. If you want to clean all files before building `all` (and you don't want to do this either), you can in fact just turn around the prerequisites of `all_targets`:

```
.PHONY: all_targets
all_targets: clean all

.PHONY: all
all:
    # ...
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    # ...
```

Again, this is really not how you want to use `make`, since it is designed to skip all the unnecessary work in the build process (that is, not recompiling those files that do not need to be recompiled, etc).

Also remember that you can call `make` with more than just one target to build. So in your example, you could also build all targets by executing

```
make all clean
```

Note that the targets will be built in the order they were passed to the command line, so the first target to be built here is `all`, followed by `clean` (which again is nonsense).

If you want to read more about how to correctly use makefiles, I suggest you to grab the book [Managing Projects with GNU Make](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596006105.do). It features a quite comprehensive explanation of almost all (GNU) Make features.

**Edit**: As [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) pointed out, the `all_targets` target in the above examples should of course be a phony target.

Comment: `all_targets` should be declared `.PHONY` too.